# python - how does one include a variable in the doc string?

Tags: python

I'm using the cmd module. there's a command that I'd like to document like this:

```
def do_this(self,arg)
    "this command accepts these values {values}".format(values="legal values")
```

the reasoning being I'd like to type that list of legal values only once. I found I can change the docstring later, but I think that's a hack. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing the docstring afterwards (by assigning to `do_this.__doc__`) is the only way.

Or if you want it to look nicer, you can use a decorator - but it still assigns to `do_this.__doc__`.

```
def doc(docstring):
    def document(func):
        func.__doc__ = docstring
        return func

    return document

@doc("this command accepts these values: {values}".format(values=[1, 2, 3])
def do_this(self, arg):
    pass
```

Comment: You should use `functools.wraps` for the decorator so you don't lose anything?

Comment: @gerrit negative, this is not a wrapper (renamed the inner func to to `document`)

Comment: clever, I'll have to check out decorators. I'm new to python, and feel like I'm drinking from a firehouse at this point.

Comment: one quick question on this. may I use that same @doc on multiple functions? or do I need a unique doc function for each do_this function?

Comment: @kdubs this is reusable, naturally. You can have it in one module and import to others as you see fit.

Comment: yes, just tried it out. seems pretty good. the doc string is still near the function.

Answer (score 1):

As you have this values in variable, you can reference to it in doc:

```
# mymodule.py
legal_values = {'one', 'two', 'three'}

def do_this(self,arg)
    """this command accepts these values: see `mymodule.legal_values`"""
```

Comment: tried this. didn't seem to work. those are backticks around legal_values?

Comment: @kdubs they work if you make a HTML document of the module contents using Sphinx, similar to the Python docs. In there there'd be a hyperlink. It wouldn't work specially in the online `help` though.

Comment: @kdubs it doesn't insert values into docstring, but it's information for user, where to find this values. When I'll type `help(do_this)` or will see `do_this` in source, i'll understand i should see `help(mymodule.legal_values)` for this values.

Comment: ah. ok. I think the other answer is what I want then. it shows up in the help with cmd