# Sphinx: Share function Docstring

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, docstring

I would like to reuse a docstring that is used for the same function across multiple classes.

For example

```
class square:
     def getArea(L,W):
     """ [description]
     L (int) ... 
     W (int) ... 

     return (int) area of shape
     """
     return L*W

 class rectangle:
     def getArea(L,W):
     """ use docstring from above"""
     return L*W
```

Is there any way to use the same docstring across multiple functions?  This is a simple example but some functions have 10 different parameters and being able to use the same docstring will ensure consistency.

Comment: Just assign to the `__doc__` attribute manually

Comment: Im sorry can you give me a little more detail.  I am new to this.  I am hoping to have some sort of central doc (.txt) with all of the shared docstrings and than just update that.

Comment: See the documentation about [`__doc__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html?highlight=__doc__#types.ModuleType.__doc__). There are several ways to do what you want, and that's why there isn't 1 single answer to this problem because it depends how you organize your objects. For example, if you reuse 1 single function why not declare it abstract or use it as a mix-in and inherit the docstring? The simple solution is setting the `__doc__` property directly as was said when declaring the class assuming you declare the function somewhere as abstract and having the docstring to reuse.

Comment: Here is [one good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36091548)